# Compiling java with Janino (broken Classpath)

Tags: java, classpath, javac, janino

I Am trying to compile very simple class with Janino:

```
import org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException;
import org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class JaninoTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CompileException {

        String sampleClass =
                "public class Test {" +
                    "public void sampleMethod() {\n" +
                    "        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();\n" +
                    "        obj.add(\"p1\", new JsonPrimitive(2));\n" +
                    "        System.out.println(obj.get(\"p1\"));\n" +
                    "}" +
                "}";

        ClassBodyEvaluator classBodyEvaluator = new ClassBodyEvaluator();
        classBodyEvaluator.setParentClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        classBodyEvaluator.setDefaultImports(new String[] {  "com.google.gson.JsonObject",
                "com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive"});
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sampleClass);
        classBodyEvaluator.cook(null, sr);
        Class<?> clazz = classBodyEvaluator.getClazz();
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());

    }


}
```

Every things works fine here, but `org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator` compiler have limitation to Java 5.
So I read on [Janino website](http://unkrig.de/w/Janino) that you can change compiler to overcome this limitation

> JANINO can be configured to use javax.tools.JavaCompiler, i.e. JAVAC,
>   which removes the Java 5-related limitations.

So I changed `ClassBodyEvaluator` on this one `org.codehaus.commons.compiler.jdk.ClassBodyEvaluator;` which is also available on Janino website and AFAIK don't have Java 5 limitation.

But unfortunately it throws following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/main/Main$Result
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:581)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.jdk.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.jdk.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.jdk.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:108)
    at JaninoTest.main(JaninoTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main$Result
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

This probably has something to do with compiler classpath but I don't see any method in API to somehow manipulate it.

I will be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: btw: you do not need to specify the class if you are using the classbodyevaluator.